# Installing a wifi-USB in offline?

Tags: wifi

I've bought the follwing Wifi USB-Stick  for a pi2 and I've trying to install it somehow! the Problem the I have is that I have No possibility to   connect the pi to internet using a LAN connection! I've found the linux driver, so I've tried the following !

[image]

does anybody has an idea how may I solve this ? 
**Update **

the WiFi that I'm trying to get connected is the AC1200 WiFi from RenForce powered by [EDiMAx EW-7822UNC](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Edimax_EW-7822UNC)!

Comment: Which 'following' wifi dongle do you have? I can't see any details. Please update your question with the relevant information. And are you sure the driver is not already available?

Comment: Please include a product page link or some identifying information about the wifi dongle.  You almost certainly do not need to be compiling a driver.

Comment: Dirk and golddilocks  thanks for replying  I've updated the question !

Comment: Is there a problem with the built in WiFi on the Pi3?

Comment: Sorry about that  NomadMaker it'S pi2 Model B

Comment: Ok, so you probably would have to compile a driver for this -- but the chances of you getting that to work are slim.  I have not seen anyone here compile a module that will work with the stock Pi kernel, even when using the correct source, version, and default Pi configuration.  This means you have to compile your own kernel.  It is not worth the $10-15 it would cost to replace the adapter with one already known to work (avoid Realtek, look for a 2.0 adapter with a Ralink chipset, then ask on here if it will work *before* you buy it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to download the driver on another computer, move it to a USB, then run the installation program on the pi from the USB.

Comment: thanks for replay but that'S what I've done  to get to this stage !

Comment: No problem! It actually is the first time I have a answer that is the correct one. Thanks!